# cannot proprely zip and unzip node_modules

Tags: zip, node-modules

I am trying to zip my node_modules directory, everything seems to work properly until I start using it.

Trying to run the following command gives me this output

```
npm run semantic-release


> @<>/<>@1.0.1 semantic-release /home/<>/Documents/<>/<>/dist
> semantic-release

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../package.json'
Require stack:
- /home/<>/Documents/<>/<>/dist/node_modules/.bin/semantic-release
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/<>/Documents/<>/<>/dist/node_modules/.bin/semantic-release:11:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/<>/Documents/<>/<>/dist/node_modules/.bin/semantic-release'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @<>/<>@1.0.1 semantic-release: `semantic-release`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @<>/<>@1.0.1 semantic-release script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/<>/.npm/_logs/2021-07-02T14_03_24_356Z-debug.log
```

However, If I go ahead and just copy the node modules in the parent directory, everything somehow works, I've checked file sizes, permissions and etc... no clue what the difference is

PS: I am using

```
zip -rq dist.zip dist
```

and

```
unzip -q dist.zip
```

Comment: We had this problem for months. And we never solved it. Now we copy/paste the entire node_modules directory, which is extremely inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and just fixed it
I am on Mac but I think this would work for linux too but probably not windows

Adding `-y` for symbolic links makes it work

```
zip -r -y -q dist.zip dist
```

and

```
unzip -q dist.zip
```